# Unused parts of the a plane ticket

Tags: tickets, cancellations, air-china

I have a problem that I would like to get a second opinion on.
I got myself a ticket plane from Frankfurt to Hanoi and back Hanoi to Frankfurt with AirChina through an online agency. Sadly, I will not be able to make the Frankfurt to Hanoi plane for personal reasons so I contracted the agency with a gentle question for a possibility of a refund of the Frankfurt to Hanoi part. Unfortunately, I wasn't successful, but fair enough, I tired!

Here's the real problem, surprisingly they also said that if I will not be able to use the Frankfurt to Hanoi part of my ticket my Hanoi to Frankfurt trip will be cancelled without any possibility for a refund. The return ticket was paid in full, it's obviously combined together under a single e-ticket with the flight numbers and reservation reference.

Have you ever heard about anything like it?

Please let me know
Martin

Comment: That’s the norm for virtually every airline. If you don’t use the first leg, the return is voided.

Comment: Also, see the [hidden-city-ticketing](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hidden-city-ticketing) tag for further discussion of people trying to use only part of a ticket and discard the rest.

Answer (score 4):

For discount or economy tickets, yes, that is the standard practice.

If any segment in the Itinerary is missed, all further segments are cancelled.

While you are unlikely to get refund, in almost all cases you can **apply the value of the ticket, minus a change fee**, to a new ticket.  That's how they call it 'non-refundable' but it doesn't make the paid amount unusable.

Comment: The last paragraph is the real answer to the underlying question: almost certainly, the asker can pay a fee to get the ticket changed to the day they now want to travel.